# What's the name of the Major scale that has 6th and 7th degree lowered?

Tags: theory, scales, terminology

What's the proper name for a scale that follows 1  2  3  4  5 b6 b7

Comment: I'd suggest removing the word 'Major' from the question title, because if a scale has flat 6 and flat 7 it's not a Major scale by definition.

Comment: I think the word "major" is important. Otherwise, "the scale that has 6th and 7th degrees lowered" means nothing, since it could be *any* scale. OP is looking for the name of a concept, and I think s/he described that concept very clearly as it is.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS the Ionian, Lydian, and Mixolydian modes are sometimes called the 'major modes', as they have the same 'major' third as the major scale. What the question describes could be thought of as (in that sense) *a* major scale, even if it isn't *the* major scale.

Comment: If I asked what Major scale has a flat 3, I doubt you'd tell me the resulting scale was still Major. All I was trying to say is that if you start with a Major and modify any of its degrees it's not, by definition, Major any more, it's a scale *derived* from a Major.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS - generally, a scale with a major third  interval between root and 3 is regarded as 'major' in some form or another.. Can't think of any exceptions. So, the way the question is posed is reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Mixolydian b6. So called because it's mainly Mixolydian, with a maj.3 and b7, with the change of M6 to m6. The 5th mode of melodic minor.So, less of a scale, more of a mode, maybe.

Comment: I've heard this scale called the "major minor scale" before, although I can't find a source for it as of now. Either way Mixolydian b6 is more clear.

Comment: "major minor" because the first 4 degrees are from the major scale and the last 4 (incl. the octave) from the natural minor (aeloic).

Comment: @JoséDavid - I guess the melodic (ascending) would then be called the 'minor major' for similar reasons?